# Python Shell not letting me create an else statement?

Tags: python, shell

Whenever I try to create an `else` statement, the shell automatically indents under the print statement,and if I put an else statement it says the following:

```
if marks<=40:
    print("failed")
else:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

So I would try to move the else by getting it inline with the previous if     statement, but it says this

```
>>> if marks <=40:
        print ("failed")
    else:

SyntaxError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
>>>
```

Any ideas of the problem? Thanks in advance

I'm also using v3.5.1 on a mac if that matters.

Comment: Try backspacing it to arrive at same intentation as `if` before writing `else`

Comment: Are you sure the shell automatically indents? put some spaces manually in front of `print`

Answer (score 2):

Add a `pass` statement to the `else` branch to skip it:

```
if condition:
    do something
else:
    pass # Do nothing.
```

The colon after `else` declares the start of an indented block, the interpreter will complain if it fails to find one. That's why you need at least one indented statement after the colon.

Also the `else` statement should be at the same indentation level as the `if` statement.

A typical Python shell looks like the following:

```
>>> if 1:
...   print 1
... else:
...   print 2
...
1
>>>
```

Comment: I'm trying to put a something into the else statement rather than skip it. So when I put ' else: ' and hit enter so I can put print("passed"), the shell will output invalid syntax.

Comment: OK, I've reproduced your error. Do not indent the `else` statement itself. The `else` statement should be at the same level as the `if` statement. Please look carefully at my above code on its indentation.